# Personalizar cookie de sessão PHP

Tags: php, segurança, cookies

Estou a utilizar um **handler** personalizado para salvar sessões no `MongoDB` e uma classe personalizada para criar **cookies** com atributo `SameSite` usando a função `header()`, embora esta especificação não seja amplamente adotada (ainda).

Contudo o **cookie** de sessão `PHP` é iniciado pela função `session_start()` que utiliza `setcookie()`, isso força a criar um **cookie** de sessão sem atributo `SameSite`.

Como personalizar o **cookie** de sessão no `PHP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado em uma resposta que recebi no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750906/php-setcookie-samesite-strict#46971326) em uma questão relacionada ao [RFC6265](http://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-same-site.html#RFC6265) que define a especificação do cookie **"same-site"** trago aqui a solução apresentada:

> Resposta no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750906/php-setcookie-samesite-strict#46971326)

Em livre tradução:

> Parece que você pode abusar do parâmetro "caminho" ou "domínio" da função "setcookie" do PHP para se esgueirar no atributo SameSite porque o PHP não escapa de ponto e vírgula:

```
setcookie('samesite-test', '1', 0, '/; samesite=strict');
```

---

Achei a resposta interessante e resolvi testar em [phtester](http://phptester.net/) usando `PHP 7.0` o atributo foi adicionado ao cookie de sessão usando Chrome 63 (desktop) e 62 (Android) além do navegador nativo no Android (62) e Opera (48)... Firefox 57 não oferece suporte más promete suporte na próxima versão (58).

Segundo [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=SameSite) os seguintes navegadores oferecem suporte a especificação (ou oferecerão):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você já viu essa lib: https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie

Modern cookie management for PHP: Esta biblioteca fornece um método estático compatível com a função setcookie (...) do PHP, mas inclui suporte para recursos mais recentes, como o atributo SameSite

Comment: Tomei como base exatamente este plugin para minha pergunta ele adiciona o atributo `SameSite` a cookies usando `header()` contudo o cookie de sessão é iniciado conforme descrevi em minha pergunta.

Comment: Com o método Session::start('Strict') ou ::start('Lax') ele inicia a sessão com método built-in do php (session_start) mas em seguida ele sobrescreve os dados da sessão adicionando o SameSite. Se essa lib não ajudar, eu não sei o que poderia ajudar então. Não há suporte nativo no PHP ainda.

Comment: Discussão sobre esse assunto no Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4na46f/samesite_cookie_support_for_php/

Comment: Pois é exatamente esta a questão. O cookie é gerado e lançado no buffer de saida, escrito (gravado) no cliente e somente depois a classe obtém o cookie e o sobrescreve por mais que este processo possa ser rápido ele não garante que não possa haver intercepção. A um issue que trata de algo similar...

Comment: https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/issues/15

Comment: Embora este issue questione um DRAFT ao php session aponta o mesmo paradigma